# groupBy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_index' pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am using

```
df.groupby(by= xxx, as_index= False)
```

And get the following error

```
groupBy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_index'
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing pandas and pyspark